# How prometheus statistics QPS in multi-process？

Tags: prometheus

I deploy my web server on k8s with multiple replicas. I use `counter` to save total request.

1. Pods share the same counter, so the counter value will be covered, should I use different counter for different pods?
2. If a pod recreate, the counter start with 0, how to handler it?

I'm confused. Is my usage wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pods have to have to be scraped separately they will have separate time series for the same metrics.
If you have a metrics called `requests` then you'll have (details depend on your setup) time series:

```
requests{instance="$pod_ip1:$port",pod="foo-1"}
requests{instance="$pod_ip2:$port",pod="foo-2"}
```

So your application should emit the same metric - it will be stored separately for every pod.

Prometheus counters are designed to handle "counter resets". Main idea is to *always* process such metric via a function that supports counter resets.
Most popular of such functions is `rate`. When `rate` will encounter a reset (counter going down) it will do the appropriate calculations (assuming there was a reset between data points).

Remember to always apply such function (`rate`, `increase`, `irate`) first and only then do any aggregations.
Example query:

```
sum( rate(requests[5m]) )
```

Will provide average rps value (during last 5 minutes) for all pods combined